# Performance Improvements using RewriteMaps-Text file

Tags: performance, rewritemap

What are the ways to improve the performance of URL redirects by using the rewrite Maps.

Currently I am using rewrite Map using the lookup keys in a text file. There are 2000 keys in the text file and the number is expected to increase by 100% in the coming months.

The text file is  in sorted order and all URL redirects are 301.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it has been a while since you asked your question, but since I got here from Google myself, I'll try to answer it anyway ;)

As you are already using RewriteMap to do the lookups using a txt file, you can very easely switch to a dbm file instead. DBM is actually a database format that uses an index, providing a much better performance when looking up keys.

You just need to do 2 simple things:

1. convert your txt file to dbm using the httxt2dbm command that comes with apache:

   ```
   httxt2dbm -in file.txt -out file.dbm
   ```
2. change your RewriteMap directive to use the dbm file instead

   ```
   RewriteMap mapname txt:/path/to/file.txt
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   RewriteMap mapname dbm:/path/to/file.dbm
   ```

The only think to keep in mind is that whenever you change your .txt file, you will need to run the httxt2dbm command again to update the .dbm file.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you for inputs Tom. The rewrite map is performing well with 3000 keys. Will try the DBM solution in prod.

Comment: Apache only reads the text file at startup, or when it changes.  Then, it keeps the entire map in memory.  For 3000 items, I doubt you'd see much difference in performance.  But for millons of keys, it makes more sense to use the dbm.